# Likelihood Ratio Test Involving Two Separate (simple) Regressions?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, maximum-likelihood, linear-model, likelihood-ratio

I'm having some trouble conceptualizing the following in a paper I've come across:

> A remark is made on using a likelihood ratio test for the following hypothesis
>
> $$\begin{align}
> H_0: \beta_{1,1} = \beta_{1,2} \\
> H_{\alpha}: \beta_{1,1} \neq \beta_{1,2}
> \end{align}
> $$
>
> where we have the model setup of
>
> $$Y_{i,j} = \beta_{0,j} + \beta_{1,j}x_i + \epsilon_{i,j},$$
>
> with $\epsilon_{i,j} \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n$ and $j \in \{1,2\}$.

I was under the impression that we could only do this for nested-models (i.e. one model has more parameters), or am I misinterpreting that/the model above? How can I specify the "full" model here to develop a test-statistic?

Comment: Can you add a full reference to the paper?